# Does Microsoft Windows 7's Windows Explorer perform any file integrity check after moving or copying a file?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-transfer, file-management, file-corruption

Does Microsoft Windows 7's Windows Explorer perform any file integrity check after moving or copying a file?

For example, Teracopy uses [CRC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/996843/395857):

[image]

Comment: Beyond the checks NTFS does itself I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.  Even if there are many sources saying Explorer copy with VERIFY ON, Microsoft told officially that

**Some versions of the MS-DOS "User's Guide" and online Help indicate that the /V (verify) switch for the COPY and XCOPY commands actually compares the source and destination files to determine whether they are identical. This is not correct. The /V switch verifies that the destination file, once written, can be read. No comparison of the files occurs.**

Reference:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/126457